# Android how to get google account photo

Tags: android, api, avatar, google-account

I want to get google account photo, I checked all the reference from web, it references using google+. But I am not allowed use that API. I think when user login the photo,it should be stored in the phone, is there anyway to get google account photo not through the google+ API?  Whether the avatar store in the device , if any function can get this photo.

I can use account get user account name but cannot get photo

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I did not get any reference. I just want to know which API I can use get the google account avatar not through google+

Comment: why you are not allowed to use that API?!

Comment: I do not have permission of that. So I have to find another solve this problem. any API can I use ?

Comment: what do you mean you don't have permission on that?

Comment: What information do you have already? The user ID? An open session?

Comment: It means I cannot use google+ get user profile.

Comment: I mean when the user google store or the user login. The avatar should store in some place, I just I want to get it through some function but not use google+. I do not think I need user id or session

Comment: So the user isn't logging into your app using their google+ account?

Comment: no if the user not login I can use default pic, but if user login, i can use their google account avatar

Comment: it is not clear why you cannot use the google+ api, except that apparently you are `not allowed use that API`, because you `do not have permission of that`, which apparently means that you `cannot use google+`. I don't get it.

Comment: policy, I cannot do anything with the google+ api~~